# How to understand the scaling of cameramatrix in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, camera, camera-calibration, fisheye

I am using openCV for image distortion of a fisheye image in python with the fisheye class.
The documentation says that the new camera matrix can be used for scaling.
For instance I use

```
Knew[(0,1),(0,1)]=0.5*Knew[(0,1),(0,1)]
```

to scale the focal length in the camera matrix.
What confuses me is the scaling parameter. The definition of focal length is the distance between image plane and "pinhole" (or the radius of the image sphere for fisheye cameras), so wouldn't it be intuitive that the image will become bigger if f is smaller?
However, if I use 0.5 as above, I actually get a larger field of view than not scaling it at all, using the same output image size.

Can anybody explain the math behind it? 
I'll have to calculate the amount of pixels for 30degrees in a fisheye and I'm using the mapping function of an equidistant fisheye (r=theta * f) but now I'm stuck on the scaling parameter.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: 
Sorry...I think I didn't explain it correctly. What I mean is that the objects will becomme bigger if f is smaller, and if I use the scaling more of the environment can be seen, using the same image size permanently (1920×1080)

Comment: You said: "so wouldn't it be intuitive that the image will become bigger if f is smaller?" and you said: "However, if I use 0.5 as above, I actually get a larger field of view than not scaling it at all, using the same output image size.". This is not a contradiction for me. In photography, a regular lens is 35 mm and when you zoom, this value increase (e.g. 70 mm).

Comment: @Catree I think I didn't explain it correctly. What I mean is that the objects will becomme bigger if f is smaller, and if I use the scaling more of the environment can be seen, using the same image size permanently (1920×1080)